# C programming basics: Why can't I see the .o file after I compile my .c file with gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-construction, object-files

I wrote a C programm and saved it with a .c extension.
Then I compiled with the gcc but after that I only see my .c file and an .exe file. The program runs perfectly. But where is the .o file that I learned in theory? Has it been overwritten to .exe and all done by the gcc in on step? (Preprocessing, compiling, assembling and linking)

I'm on a VM running Debian.

Comment: use `gcc -c <c_file_name>` option to generate object file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `gcc` compiles and links in one step.  To get a `.o` file, you need to compile without linking.  That's done with the `-c` option.

Suppose you want to compile two files separately, then link them.  You would do the following:

```
gcc -c file1.c      # creates file1.o
gcc -c file2.c      # creates file2.o
gcc -o myexe file1.o file2.o
```

If you want just the output of the preprocessor, use the `-E` option along with the `-o` to specify the output file:

```
gcc -E file1.c -o file1-pp.c    # creates file1-pp.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Compile and link in two steps:

```
gcc -Wall -c tst.c
gcc tst.c -o tst
```

After first command you'll get a `.o` file.

Answer (score 1):

if you did something like `gcc test.c` then it produces only the executable file (in order to compile only, see the `-c` option)

Answer (score 0):

here is steps on compiling with gcc to create a .o file from your C file:

http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/manual/html_node/Creating-object-files.html

Comment: yes thanks, gcc -c <...> worked. But why does the command gcc -o don't create the object file and the .exe file? Does it delete it after it has linked it? Does the command (.o) do everything at once?